# Convenience Methods in Python

Tags: python

I have been steadily getting acquainted with Python over the last 6 months.

I have heard of several people speaking of 'convenience methods' (typically within the context of classes), but I am unclear as to what this should mean. I cannot find any documentation on so-called 'convenience methods'.

Would someone care to explain what is meant by 'convenience methods' in Python?

Thanks

Comment: It's what it says on the tin: a method or function that is there for convenience. Maybe it removes all punctuation from a string, or provides an implementation of a linked list. The term means the same thing in any language.

Answer (score 0):

> Convenience methods, also known as "helper methods", are methods which provide commonly used functionality. They generally have no state or minimal state, where all or nearly all of the objects to be used are passed in. Methods can also be called convenience methods when they reduce clutter in the calling methods (to ensure all method lengths are small).

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ConvenienceMethods